# Redirect url with Variable in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How to Redirect Url in following format:

My code:

```
return Redirect::to('home/viewcustomer/$cusid')
    ->with('status','success')
    ->with('message','success');
```

Example :

`home/viewcustomer/8`

Comment: try this `Redirect::to('home/viewcustomer/'.$cusid)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to take care about your [string quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) while using variables within string quotes. Just update your code

```
Redirect::to('home/viewcustomer/$cusid')
```

into

```
Redirect::to("home/viewcustomer/$cusid")
            ^^                        ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i usually use

Session and Redirect so you have to define it in your controller

```
Use Session;
Use Redirect;
```

Then

```
public function example(){
 Session::flash('status','Your message');
 return Redirect::to('/yourRoute');
}
```

If you want to show your message in your view you have to do this...

```
@if(Session::has('status'))
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <p><strong>Success!!</strong> </p>
            <ul>
                <li>{{ Session::get('status') }}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif
```

Hope this helps!!

Ps: Sorry for the bad english :)